# Using javascript linking between issue list and document library

Tags: javascript, document, library

I'm making a issue list that should have link to a document library. After registrered I want the dispform.aspx to show a link to the library with filter on the ID from the issue list.

I know ID can't be fetched from the form, but is it possible to retrieve it from the http address and put it in with the link with javascript?

/Forms/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=look&FilterValue1=**My ID from HTTP**

//Stian

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint you can use `_spGetQueryParam` to get a url param like your ID ([details on my blog](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/))

```
var id = _spGetQueryParam("ID");
var url = "/Forms/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=look&FilterValue1=" + id;
```

Comment: This is an absolutely brilliant find!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to get item Id from display (or edit) form address. They usually have this kind of address:

```
Lists/Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=35&So
```

You can parse `ID` attribute using this javascript:

```
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]ID=([^&#]*)");
var itemIdValue = regex.exec(window.location.href);
var itemId = itemIdValue[1];
```